# Extract information from an unordered_map containing of unordered_maps

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

my problem is a little complex to explain. So I will try to make myself as clear as possible. I am working on a C ++ application implementation like that of Citymapper. At the current level, I use two unordered_maps one of which is nested in the other and at the end a vector of pairs. I also have two .csv files, one of which the different metro stations, a key for unorder_map and different other information and the other which contains the connections between the different stations (key of departure, key of the arrival, travel_time). I specify that compute_travel counts for two stations in direct connection. I'm trying to pull the travel_time between two stations (from, to) or (_start, _end in uint64) from _start and _end. I implemented two functions: compute_travel and compute_and_display_travel. The first one extracts the travel_time and the second shows the movement between the stations.

Here it is without delay (excuse my french):

```
vector<pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> > Station_parser:: compute_travel(uint64_t _start, uint64_t _end){
    vector<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> > vect; //RA1I ?

    int travel_time=0; //RA1I 
    for(auto& j:connections_hashmap){
        for(auto&i:(j.second)){//pour chaque noeud de l'unordered_map connections de connections_hashmap
            if ((i.first==_start)&&(i.second==_end)){ //on recherche le couple départ-destination 
                 travel_time=j.first; //on récupère le travel_time de la connection répond au critère
            }


            else
                cout<<"Erreur"<<endl;
        }
    }

    vect.push_back(make_pair(_start,travel_time));
    return vect;  
}


vector<std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> > Station_parser::compute_and_display_travel(uint64_t _start, uint64_t _end){
    vector<pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> > vect=compute_travel(_start,_end);
    for(auto &i:vect){

         cout << i.first << "," << i.second << endl;
    }
    return vect;
}
```

My code compiles but my travel_time is set to 0 as if the program was not going into the last loop (which is not normal). I'm supposed to get the travel_time that is in my .csv file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: ... and please translate the comments if they carry valuable information. If they don't, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood what you are trying to do. I do not understand what you mean by "not going through the last loop". The code, as is, looks okay. However, maps should not be used in this example in my opinion. Also, there seem to be unneeded copies, vector allocations, ... But let's consider all of this out of scope.

Most probably, your data is loaded incorrectly into your maps (you don't show how you load the data from the input files). This could explain as well why your travel time is set to 0: you initialize `int travel_time=0;`, and if no elements are found in `connections_hashmap`, or in `j.second`, or if `((i.first==_start)&&(i.second==_end))` returns `false`, then `travel_time` will remain equal to 0 and be pushed into the `vector` which your return.

I tried this small example to show that your code should work provided your data is loaded correctly and you call your functions with the correct arguments `start` and `end` (you should add some exceptions or default behavior - the default behavior in the current code is setting your time to 0).

```
// time, start, end
std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_map<int,int>> connections;

std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> compute_travel(int start, int end)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vect;

    int travel_time=0;

    // what if connections is empty?
    for(const auto& [time,connectedStations] : connections)
    {
        // what if connectedStations is empty?
        for(const auto& [s,e] : connectedStations)
        {
            if ( s == start && e == end)
                 travel_time = time;
            else // and what happens here?
                std::cout<< "Erreur" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    vect.push_back(std::make_pair(start,travel_time));
    return vect;  
}


std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > compute_and_display_travel(int start, int end)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > vect = compute_travel(start,end);
    for(const auto& i : vect)
        std::cout << "depart station: " << i.first << ", time: " << i.second << std::endl;
    return vect;
}

int main()
{
    // 4 mins from station 1 to station 2
    connections[4][1] = 2;
    compute_and_display_travel(1,2);

    return 0;
}

// output: depart station: 1, time: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks, i actually don't understand what is going on right now. I use two functions : read stations and read connections. Read stations is working fine (overloaded << operator to verify) but it's like read_connections "doesn't even work". I inserted a print on the first line of the function but it doesn't print. Here is the code :

```
        void Station_parser::read_connections(const std::string& _filename){
    cout<<"hi"<<endl; //?????????
    ifstream entree(_filename.c_str()); 
    if (entree.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error"<<endl;
    }              
    string from=" ";
    string to=" ";
    string tfr=" ";//travel_time
    while(entree.good()){
        getline(entree,from,',');
        getline(entree,to,',');
        getline(entree,tfr,'\n'); //go to next line
        uint64_t fr=strtoul(from.c_str(),NULL,10);//base 10
        uint64_t t=strtoul(to.c_str(),NULL,10);
        uint64_t tf_time=strtoul(tfr.c_str(),NULL,10);
        connections.insert({fr,t});
        connections_hashmap.insert({tf_time,connections});
    }
    entree.close();
}
```

Unfortunately i can't use a debugger since i'm working on notepad++ and compiling on a linux bash. I tried to use code::blocks but it doesn't build  and that's sad.

Comment: You should keep the answer section for answers.

Comment: Try to get a minimal example. It's impossible to help you this way. Possibly, when you code the minimal example, you'll understand where your mistake is.

Comment: I don't know how to add code in the comments section. Anyway what do you mean by a minimal example ? Because, right now, my biggest issue is the fact that my read_connections function is not even working.

Comment: You have not shared the read_connections function, so I can't comment on that. You should try to get it working on code::blocks or any other IDE and debug.

Comment: I did share the read_connections function. It's my second post. I tried to get it working on cde::blocks but i got an error message i didn't have earlier : excepted class before '{' token. I'm supposed to have this. I'm kind of lost right now

Comment: Ok, I see the function, but how can I comment on it without knowing the input data? Your error in code::blocks is because your code doesn't compile.
I cannot help you any further. Read the guidelines of how to ask a question on stackoverflow. There you'll find out what a minimal example is.